# Easiest way to represent a list of string pairs literally in c#?

Tags: c#, literals, keyvaluepair

I want to create several short (ordered) lists of pairs of strings, and have a neat literal representation in code. Is there a nice way to do this? Best I could come up with is

```
     using Pairs = System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary;
     ...
            var z = new Pairs()
            {
                { "a", "b" },
                { "c", "d" }
            };
```

but the lack of type safety is a bit horrible. There doesn't seem to be a generic ordered dictionary.

What other classes have literal initializer syntax? Is it possible to define your own initializer syntax for a class?

Comment: `SortedDictionary<TK,TV>`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx

Comment: What is the scope of usage? If it's local method's scope, you can use list of anonymous objects.

Comment: @Ilya - I need to create an object that can be passed around. I don't know much about anonymous objects - could I somehow use them within a local method to create a non-anonymous object (such as `List<KeyValuePair>`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `n`-by-2 array allows this initializer syntax:

```
string[,] z = { { "a", "b" }, { "c", "d" }, { "z", "w" }, };
```

In this case dimensions are 3-by-2.

If you prefer an array of arrays, `string[][]`, the syntax is just a bit more clumpsy. Some rows could accidentally (or intentionally) have a different length than the others ("jagged" array). An array of arrays might be easier to order using `Array.Sort` on the "outer" array, with some `IComparer<string[]>` or `Comparison<string[]>`.

Otherwise, use `SortedDictionary<string, string>` or `SortedList<string, string>` as already suggested in a comment by `spender`:

```
var z = new SortedDictionary<string, string> { { "a", "b" }, { "c", "d" }, { "z", "w" }, };
```

Any type, including user-defined types, that has an (accessible and non-static) `Add` method which takes in two strings, will allow this sort of collection initializer. For example:

```
var z = new YourType { { "a", "b" }, { "c", "d" }, { "z", "w" }, };
```

will be roughly equivalent to:

```
YourType z;
{
    var temp = new YourType();
    temp.Add("a", "b");
    temp.Add("c", "d");
    temp.Add("z", "w");
    z = temp;
}
// use variable z here
```

Comment: Excellent - I never knew that! Is this restricted to strings? Presumably the compiler simply inserts calls to Add(), and what my custom defined type does with them is up to me (conventions aside)?

Comment: @Rob The number and type of arguments can be varied. The compiler will perform overload resolution as usual to determine what non-static overload of `Add` to call. It is a requirement that `YourType` implements `IEnumerable`, in which case the compiler will think "`YourType` is a collection (`IEnumerable`), then I shall allow collection initializer syntax". It is not necessarily the same overload of `Add` which is called for each element in the list. The `Add` method can even be generic if the type argument can be inferred (type inference). Really flexible ...

Comment: TIL about the string[,] syntax! It's easy to iterate through with a for loop like a regular array with the queryParams[i,0] fomat.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `Tuple` class - it abstracts nicely over a pair.
Something like:

```
new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
            {
                Tuple.Create("a", "b"),
                Tuple.Create("c", "d"),                    
            };
```

Comment: Ok - I did effectively this, using `KeyValuePair` (we're still on .Net 3.5) and created a method with a shorter name (`Pair`) to perform construction. Would still prefer to be able to avoid the constructor altogether

Answer (score 0):

There's no generic OrderedDictionary, but there's a generic [`SortedDictionary`](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Ff7fta44c.aspx&ei=LLOxUeawKK2y7Ab9hoHAAw&usg=AFQjCNFDXeTxBm3I0e67cGKCOs05B-J85A&bvm=bv.47534661,d.ZGU). Use that instead.

Comment: Unfortunately the order of the pairs is important

Comment: The order if the *pairs*, not the order of the key? You shouldn't use a dictionary, then, just a `List<Tuple<String,String>>`

Comment: Or maybe use `SortedSet<Tuple<string, string>>` if on .NET 4.0 or newer? Depending on how to compare two pairs (`Tuple<,>` does it lexicographically).